# Replicate Iframe to another user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am showing some websites in a iframe on my rails application. What I want is to replicate same iframe content to another user in a different browser. For example if person 1 clicking link in iframe it has to reflect in person 2 browser iframe. Give me some ideas to accomplish this one.

Comment: you should do it with websockets. In Rails 5 they are implemented with `ActionCable` http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html

Comment: Yes, I can able to do with websocket or faye. I need some specific idea to do

Comment: was it helpful my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst this question is pretty broad, you should definitely use websockets in order to achieve it.

You can refer to the [official documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html) of **ActionCable**.

You will find a plenty of tutorials, such as:

- This [RubyInside](https://medium.com/rubyinside/action-cable-hello-world-with-rails-5-1-efc475b0208b)
- *Learn Enough Action Cable to Be Dangerous* book by [Micheal Hartl](https://www.learnenough.com/action-cable-tutorial)

Another approach could be to use a ReactJS component instead of your iframe (see this [quickstart guide](https://www.airpair.com/reactjs/posts/reactjs-a-guide-for-rails-developers))